# Does a Truetype version of the Fixed Misc bitmap font exist?

Tags: fonts

[image: terminal]

Does there exist a Truetype version of this font?

Comment: You could try : http://underpop.online.fr/l/linux-console-fonts-for-windows-in-ttf-and-fon/fonts/misc-fixed.ttf (no guarantee of any kind)